# Nautilus Not Working

Tags: 12.04, nautilus

The "Open a New Window" selection in Nautilus stopped working today. I closed all my windows and when I tried to restart Nautilus by clicking on the folder icon, it flashed as if it was trying to start up and then just quit again. Does anyone know what caused this bug and how to fix it?

Comment: Launch Nautilus form the Terminal and paste the output into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem. It was a memory issue. I closed some apps, then ran `nautilus -q` and restarted it through the unity menu.

Answer (score 2):

I think it because of nautilus corrupted. Just reinstall nautilus.
press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> then enter

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall nautilus
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think I solved it (see my edit)